# angularjs routes with the same definition loops

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using $stateProvider to define my routes, and I'm facing issues where if I have two routes with the same number of path parameters they go in a loop with each other and though I'm using ui-sref with the name of the route specifically.

for example :

```
$stateProvider
    .state( {
        name: 'main',
        url: '/{clientId}',
        templateUrl: '/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
})
```

is getting in a loop with :

```
.state('battview_mobile',{
            url: '/batteries',
            templateUrl: 'modules/batteries/views/batteries.html',
            controller: 'batterieseCtrl',
})
```

though in the HTML I call :

```
ui-sref="battview_mobile"
```

Can you advise me why it's happening though I'm naming my state to go to?

Comment: You haven't set `name` parameter in the `battview_mobile`

Answer (score 1):

Your second state is missing the name parameter:
Also your are passing a parameter `clientId` with the wrong way. It should be `:clientId` That means this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main',{
        url: '/:clientId',
        templateUrl: '/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
})
    .state('battview_mobile',{
        url: '/batteries',
        templateUrl: 'modules/batteries/views/batteries.html',
        controller: 'batterieseCtrl',
})
```

Comment: Hi @Vassilis Pits Thanks can you explain a bit? what's the difference between  .state('main',{}) and  .state( {name:'main'}) ?  I'm starting to work on this already developed site and it already has more than 60 routes using those two different structure, so this will mean I will need to apply the same structure to all ,will that break anything?

Comment: Well it is not consistent and you can expect issues. There is no actual difference but you should use only one structure in order to work without issues. Glad I helped, an acceptance will be much appreciated ;)

Comment: I have just tried it but it did not solve the loop, the only thing that solves it is when I change the url to url: '/batteries/' instead of url: '/batteries', which is to have a different url syntax than main

Comment: @sisimh I just realise that your are passing `{clientId}` instead of `:clientId`. Check my updated answer please and tel me if it's ok now

Comment: sorry that did not make a difference, {cientId} works like :clientId

Comment: Please preserve logs in your console and share any error that you're getting. states are correct now so probably something is wrong with the code in those two controllers.